# Could someone please explain why I'm getting this error message and how to fix it?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Upon trying to knit, I'm getting this message (I have no idea what I'm doing as this is literally my first time ever using R)

Quitting from lines 39-57 (Assignment-01-template.Rmd)
Error: Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?

Lines 39-57:

```
library(usmap)

# Hex color codes for Democrat Blue and Republican Red
party_colors <- c("#2E74C0", "#CB454A") 

# plot_usmap(data = election, values = "party", color = "white") + 
           scale_fill_manual(values = party_colors) + 
           theme(legend.position = "right") +
           labs(title = "Winning Party for States") + labs(fill = "Party")


plot_usmap(data = election, values = "r_points", color = "black", exclude = c("DC")) + 
          scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue4", 
                                high = "red4", breaks = c(-45, -30, -15, 0, 15, 30, 45)) +
          theme(legend.position = "right") +
          labs(title = "Winning Margins for Republican") + labs(fill = "Margin")
```

Comment: Is it simply that the first `plot_usmap()` is commented out, so you are trying to add layers to a plot object that was not initialised? Just try removing the `#` before `plot_usmap`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that this line:

```
# plot_usmap(data = election, values = "party", color = "white") +
```

does not run because it is commented out (starts with `#`).

That line initialises the plot so in subsequent lines, you are trying to add layers to something (a ggplot object) that does not exist. Hence the error:

> Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object

If you want the first `plot_usmap` to run, you need to remove the `#` before it. If you don't want it to run, you need to comment out the subsequent lines too (down to and including the first `labs` line).